# Using max with a list of GPathResults

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a list of GPathResults who all have an attribute 'seq' in them
For ex:

```
GPathResult gath;
Integer int = gath.seq.toInteger()
```

Now I want to select the GPathResult that has the maximum 'seq'?

If I have 10 GPathResult's with 10 value of 'seq', I need to grab the GPathResult with the maximum 'seq' value

Is there any Groovier way to do this rather than comparing each GPathResult with the next one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`max` method that takes a Closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#max%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

```
def gpathWithMaxSeq = listOfGpaths.max { it.seq.toInteger() }
```

From the documentation:

> If the closure has two parameters it is used like a traditional Comparator. [...] Otherwise, the Closure is assumed to take a single parameter and return a Comparable (typically an Integer) which is then used for further comparison.

If some of the GPathResults may not have a `seq` then you may need something more like this (untested)

```
def gpathWithMaxSeq = listOfGpaths.max {
  it.seq ? it.seq.toInteger() : Integer.MIN_VALUE
}
```

(`MIN_VALUE` to make items without a `seq` compare as smaller than those with).

Comment: Thanks. this works for all the cases except if I have a GPathResult in the collections that does not have a 'seq' element in it. I get a 'numberFormatException' in such case. Any way to overcome this..

Comment: @user1717230 If the value you get back when you ask a GPathResult for a non-existent key is Groovy-false then you could use a ternary conditional.

Comment: Thanks for the update...Still seeing the same 'numberFormatException' though

Comment: This worked:    def gpathWithMaxSeq = listOfGpaths.max {
  it.seq.isEmpty() ? Integer.MIN_VALUE: it.seq.toInteger()
}

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have you tried</s>

```
results*.seq*.toInteger().max()
```

That will give you the max value of seq which isn't what you asked for. Ian has the solution above

Or I guess you could do

```
results.sort( false ) { -it.seq.toInteger() }.head()
```

Comment: That would give you the highest `seq` value from among the values on all the items, not the item that this highest value belongs to.

Comment: Ahhh...true ... whoops

Answer (score 0):

numberFormatException means that attribute is exist, but is empty.

Your solution is working, but this one may be safer

`list.max {(it?.@seq ?: Integer.MIN_VALUE).toInteger()}`

Full example

```
def p = new XmlParser().parseText("<root><node seq='1'/><node/><node seq='3'/><node seq=''/></root>")
def a = (0..3).collect{ p.node[it]}
a.each {println(it.@seq)} // some debug output
a.max {(it?.@seq ?: Integer.MIN_VALUE).toInteger()} // actual searching. Elvis operator to set default values if it.seq is not exist or empty. Will be a little more safer solution.
```

Comment: Thanks...Just for my info, Do you see any issue with my solution(After Modifying Ian's solution)?..Any cases where it would be unsafe?

Comment: @user1717230 If you about `def gpathWithMaxSeq = listOfGpaths.max { it.seq.isEmpty() ? Integer.MIN_VALUE: it.seq.toInteger() }` yes. If it.seq == null you will get NPE while calling 'isEmpty()' method.

Comment: I added a safe navigation operator as well..def gpathWithMaxSeq = listOfGpaths.max { it.seq?.isEmpty() ? Integer.MIN_VALUE: it.seq?.toInteger() }